# How do you show a column value degrading over time with Pandas Rolling?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe of future projections of a value that I want to show reducing over time by a specified amount.

I want to go from this:

```
Group   Period  Value

A   1/1/2020    4.3

A   2/1/2020

A   3/1/2020

A   4/1/2020

A   5/1/2020

A   6/1/2020

A   7/1/2020

A   8/1/2020

A   9/1/2020

B   1/1/2020    6.5

B   2/1/2020

B   3/1/2020

B   4/1/2020

B   5/1/2020

B   6/1/2020

B   7/1/2020

B   8/1/2020

B   9/1/2020
```

To this:

```
Group   Period  Value

A   1/1/2020    4.3

A   2/1/2020    3.3

A   3/1/2020    2.3

A   4/1/2020    1.3

A   5/1/2020    0.3

A   6/1/2020    0

A   7/1/2020    0

A   8/1/2020    0

A   9/1/2020    0

B   1/1/2020    6.5

B   2/1/2020    5.5

B   3/1/2020    4.5

B   4/1/2020    3.5

B   5/1/2020    2.5

B   6/1/2020    1.5

B   7/1/2020    0.5

B   8/1/2020    0

B   9/1/2020    0
```

I already have the dataframe created with the value in the starting position (in this example, 1/1/2020).

There was an attempt. See below.

```
group = df2.groupby(['region', 'site', 'product_ID'], as_index=False)

df2['Projected_S'] = group['Projected_S'].rolling(window=1).apply(lambda x: x.shift(1)-1)
```

Comment: Do you know beforehand the starting positions?

Comment: I do. My code has gotten me as far as populating the first entry in the projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use something like:

```
f=lambda x: np.where(x.ffill()-x.ffill().expanding().count()<0
                 ,0,x.ffill()-x.ffill().expanding().count())
df.Value=df.groupby(df.Value.notna().cumsum())['Value'].transform(f)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Group    Period  Value
0      A  1/1/2020    3.3
1      A  2/1/2020    2.3
2      A  3/1/2020    1.3
3      A  4/1/2020    0.3
4      A  5/1/2020    0.0
5      A  6/1/2020    0.0
6      A  7/1/2020    0.0
7      A  8/1/2020    0.0
8      A  9/1/2020    0.0
9      B  1/1/2020    5.5
10     B  2/1/2020    4.5
11     B  3/1/2020    3.5
12     B  4/1/2020    2.5
13     B  5/1/2020    1.5
14     B  6/1/2020    0.5
15     B  7/1/2020    0.0
16     B  8/1/2020    0.0
17     B  9/1/2020    0.0
```

***Explanation***:
 `df.Value.notna().cumsum()` creates groups starting from row which has entry to the next valid value. Then we use `.ffill()` to fill the values downwards. Then using `expanding()` we take count so basically it subtracts the value with the expanding count.

Finally using `np.where()` to check where is a negative value and replacing them with 0. :)

Comment: what kind of dark arts is this? totally works, but i can't say i understand what you have done here. thank you!

Comment: @Question_Mark i added some explainations. :) Cheers..!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution reminding my Excel days, when I used to use a lot of helper columns(only to delete them after hehehe).
Assuming you know the starting position, and that the dataframe is structured as you stated in the question, the following procedure works:

1. Make sure the date information is properly converted to date object
2. Set a multi-index in the dataframe composed by the groups names and dates
3. Count the number of elements for each group
4. Create a helper array consisting of repetitions of the values you want to see decreasing, with as many repetitions as the number of elements in each group, call it A
5. Create another array with the amount you want to subtract, call it B
6. C = A - B
7. Replace negative values with 0
8. Assign new values to column in question

   Here is the code:

   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd
   import datetime as dt

   ## Enforce conversion to date object

   def date_converter(x):
   return dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y")

   test["Period"] = test["Period"].apply(date_converter)
   test.set_index(["Group", "Period"], inplace=True)
   starting_pos = "01-01-2020"
   forecast_col = "Value"

   ## Get the names of the groups

   u = test.index.unique(0).tolist()

   ## Get all the instances of all groups

   f = test.index.get_level_values(0).tolist()
   A = []
   B = []
   for element in u:
   # Query the value you want to decrease
   value = float(test.loc[(element, starting_pos), forecast_col])
   # Count how many elements there are for each group
   x = f.count(element)
   # Repeat value x times
   y = [value]*x
   # Append repetitions to global result
   A = A + y
   # Create array you want to subtract with len(x)
   B = B + [n for n in range(x)]
   to_zero = lambda x: np.where(x < 0, 0, x)
   C = pd.Series(np.array(A) - np.array(B)).apply(to_zero)
   test.loc[:,"Value"] = C.values
   test

   Although [anky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55748117/how-do-you-show-a-column-value-degrading-over-time-with-pandas-rolling/55748420#55748420) already posted an answer, I just wanted to give another option, that I consider simpler but that can do the job. I'll let you do the performance comparison.